# Usage of SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase

Tags: android, design-patterns

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase%28%29

> Once opened successfully, the database is cached, so you can call this
>   method every time you need to write to the database.

Consider the following snippet:

```
SQLiteDatabase db1 = openHelperImplObj.getWritableDatabase();
// do something with db1
SQLiteDatabase db2 = openHelperImplObj.getWritableDatabase();
// do something with db2
db2.close();
// do something with db1
db1.close();
```

I presume the **second call to getWritableDatabase()** will return the same cached DB (the **db1**), wouldn't the line db2.close() cause any issue to db1 operations that happen afterward? If so, what is the recommended way to avoid such problem since the second call may happen anywhere, i.e. in a different function or even in different class.

Comment: On second thought, I guess I have to just avoid direct use/reference of SQLiteDatabase everywhere in my code, but let only minimum number of designated classes to do the jobs that dealing with SQLiteDatabase directly. This doesn't sound like Android specific question but more like a general design problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a data base by using db  `openHelperImplObj.getWritableDatabase();`
then following thing check

`1>`If database is not created then it create database and open it for write mode else created first then open.

`2>`Second and most important what i have observed if data base is already created then it opened it but if its open already it do nothing, `That means it occupy the old instance of data`
base that open DB already until you close it.Thats why its better practice to close DB once it
use over

Hope you got