# Error while putting data into database in android

Tags: android

I am creating an application which requires login. I created the main and the login activity.so when i insert username and password it should save into database.
i am getting these errors when i am installing the app.

```
    10-05 23:12:18.959 18728-18728/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.onCreate(DatabaseOperations.java:23)
10-05 23:12:18.959 18728-18728/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.PutInformation(DatabaseOperations.java:32)
10-05 23:16:45.809 18970-18970/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.onCreate(DatabaseOperations.java:23)
10-05 23:16:45.809 18970-18970/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.PutInformation(DatabaseOperations.java:32)
10-05 23:26:21.659 31040-31040/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.onCreate(DatabaseOperations.java:23)
10-05 23:26:21.659 31040-31040/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.PutInformation(DatabaseOperations.java:32)
10-05 23:28:34.489 31330-31330/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.onCreate(DatabaseOperations.java:23)
10-05 23:28:34.489 31330-31330/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.PutInformation(DatabaseOperations.java:32)
10-05 23:45:53.309 31935-31935/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.onCreate(DatabaseOperations.java:23)
10-05 23:45:53.309 31935-31935/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.PutInformation(DatabaseOperations.java:32)
10-05 23:48:01.659 32267-32267/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.onCreate(DatabaseOperations.java:23)
10-05 23:48:01.659 32267-32267/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.PutInformation(DatabaseOperations.java:32)
10-05 23:56:57.979 32571-32571/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.onCreate(DatabaseOperations.java:24)
10-05 23:56:57.979 32571-32571/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.PutInformation(DatabaseOperations.java:33)
10-05 23:58:57.249 451-451/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.onCreate(DatabaseOperations.java:23)
10-05 23:58:57.249 451-451/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.PutInformation(DatabaseOperations.java:32)
10-06 00:02:41.189 898-898/com.example.shoaib.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.onCreate(DatabaseOperations.java:23)
10-06 00:02:41.189 898-898/com.example.shoaib.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.PutInformation(DatabaseOperations.java:32)
10-06 00:04:54.439 1175-1175/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.onCreate(DatabaseOperations.java:23)
10-06 00:04:54.439 1175-1175/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.PutInformation(DatabaseOperations.java:32)
10-06 00:05:57.279 1426-1426/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.onCreate(DatabaseOperations.java:23)
10-06 00:05:57.279 1426-1426/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.PutInformation(DatabaseOperations.java:32)
10-06 00:07:16.629 1733-1733/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.onCreate(DatabaseOperations.java:23)
10-06 00:07:16.629 1733-1733/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shoaib.myapplication.DatabaseOperations.PutInformation(DatabaseOperations.java:32)
```

this one is the DatabaseOperations.java file

```
package com.example.shoaib.myapplication;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by shoaib on 10/5/2015.
 */
public class DatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final int database_version=1;
    public String CREATE_QUERY="CREATE TABLE "+tableData.tableInfo.TABLE_NAME+"("+tableData.tableInfo.USER_NAME+" TEXT, "+tableData.tableInfo.USER_PASS+" TEXT, );";
    public DatabaseOperations(Context context) {
        super(context, tableData.tableInfo.DATABASE_NAME, null, database_version);
        Log.d("Database Operations","Database Created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb) {
        sdb.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
        Log.d("Database Operations", "Table Created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
    public void PutInformation(DatabaseOperations dop,String name,String pass){
        SQLiteDatabase SQ=dop.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(tableData.tableInfo.USER_NAME,name);
        cv.put(tableData.tableInfo.USER_PASS, pass);
        long k=SQ.insert(tableData.tableInfo.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
        Log.d("Database Operations","one row inserted");
    }
}
```

Comment: actual exception is not in your post. I believe some part of exception output is missing. btw, it seems you dont call onCreate from PutInformation. so you should not get such exception from this code in my opinion

Comment: so for that what changes i have to make?

Comment: @Adem you mean to say that i am not calling onCreate() method but that executes automatically so it does't need to be called form PutInformation().

Comment: how do you save "name" and "pass". please post how you create DatabaseOperations and how you call PutInformation

Comment: DatabaseOperations DB = new DatabaseOperations(ctx);
                DB.PutInformation(DB,name,pass);  @Adem

Comment: I think you should not call "dop.getWritableDatabase();" everytime. you should keep SQLiteDatabase in class level. so you have to have only one SQLiteDatabase that you only get once with getWritableDatabase. read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015731/android-sqlite-example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888512/usage-of-sqliteopenhelper-getwritabledatabase Read this @Adem

Comment: it seems your exception is not full. so, I can not understand what is wrong. possible reason, you might try to open same db multiple times. for instance, do you create multiple instance of DatabaseOperations ? without closing previous

Comment: No there are't multiple instances

Comment: that's not the code that throws that stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the logcat you'll see exception name and full stacktrace:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE table_name(username TEXT, pass TEXT, );
```

Remove the redundant last comma from the query:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(username TEXT, pass TEXT, );
//                                              ^ this one
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create table you have to add column  `_id Integer primary key`.

Comment: actually you don't. you should, because it will be easier to use a CursorAdapter, but that is not a requirement.